# Чистый Java web-app БЕЗ web.xml на Servlet, как конфигурировать без фреймворков?

Tags: java, servlet, аннотации, web.xml

Доброго времени всем!
Не так давно начал изучать Java и сейчас хочу написать учебный проект на чистом Java, без Spring  и т.д. для того чтобы разобраться как все работает "под капотом".

Как написать конфигурацию без фреймворков ?
Где почитать ?

Comment: А чем вам `web.xml` не угодил?

Comment: Ничем, просто хочется знать как сделать без него )
Вот и спрашиваю у опытных где почитать

могли бы Вы мне помочь с этим https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706231/servlet-ajax-jsp-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83-jsp

Comment: Используйте embeddable веб-серверы, не связаные с Java EE и сервлетами: Undertow, Jetty, Ratpak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Минимальный сервер на Java пишется при помощи [ServerSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html):

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(12345);
        while (true) {
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            new Thread(new SocketProcessor(s)).start();
        }
    }

    private static class SocketProcessor implements Runnable {
        private Socket s;

        public SocketProcessor(Socket s) {
            this.s = s;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
                os.write("Hello world!".getBytes());
                os.flush();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    s.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Запустив этот код и открыв в браузере http://localhost:12345/, вы увидите фразу *Hello World!*.

Само собой, чтобы это больше походило на веб-приложение, нужно научить этот сервер разбирать хэдеры и параметры запроса (читая их напрямую из `Socket.getInputStream()`), отдавать какой-нибудь контент (читая его из файлов или формируя динамически), шифровать коммуникации с пользователем (если захотите, чтобы работал по HTTPS), ограничивать число подключений (не создавать новый поток-обработчик для каждого запроса, а выдавать потоки из фиксированного пула, чтобы не заддосили), работать с сессиями и т. д. Реализовывать всё это в учебных целях допустимо, но для реальных проектов лучше пользоваться уже существующими решениями.

Чуть менее минимальная реализация пишется при помощи [com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/jre/api/net/httpserver/spec/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpServer.html). Там за вас уже сделано много работы по разбору запросов и привязке обработчиков к конкретным урлам.

Comment: *Чуть менее минимальная реализация пишется при помощи com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.*  Но для чего-то минимально серьезного его не стоит использовать.

Comment: Для чего-то более-менее серьёзного всегда стоит использовать проверенные решения, и минимализм, чаще всего, неуместный критерий. Но в вопросе озвучивалась задача *разобраться как все работает "под капотом"*, а для этого сойдёт и такое.

Comment: Я понял, что слабоват еще для такой реализации =)
Пометил ответ